# How do I confirm a kernel flag is running from within my Linux Desktop?

Tags: linux, grub2

If I set a flag on the Linux kernel during boot, is there a way to confirm that flag is running?

For example if I set the flag `iommu=on`, can I check from within Linux if it is?

I ask because I was made aware the UEFI boot may interfere with Linux flags and I'd like to sanity check

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command `cat /proc/cmdline`.

Using that command you can avoid using sudo because the file cmdline is in read mode for everyone.

**Update:** I tested with `dmesg` and it's not necessary to use sudo, both scripts are correct but I would rather use the `cat /proc/cmdline` command than `dmesg` command.

Answer (score 0):

The second line of the output of `dmesg` should tell you the boot flags. For example, these are the first two lines of my system:

```
~ # dmesg
[Feb10 18:02] Linux version 5.16.8-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 11.1.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 08 Feb 2022 21:21:08 +0000
[  +0.000000] Command line: root=/dev/nvme1n1p3 rw quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1 nowatchdog audit=0 initrd=amd-ucode.img initrd=initramfs-linux.img
...
```

Comment: Perfect, I ran `sudo dmesg | grep "Command line:"` and found it. Thank you